# Changing numberFormat from Dollar to British Pound

Tags: coldfusion, currency-formatting

I'm trying to format a currency value to output in GBP, but I'm having trouble trying to change from $ to £. I currently have the following...

```
numberFormat(TOTAL_VALUE_GBP,'_$,9.99')
```

What do I need to do to output as a £?

Comment: Historically, most of the base CF functions (date, numeric, etc...) use en_US formats (only). To support other locales, use the [International version](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/international-functions.html) of that function (LSNumberFormat, LSDateFormat, etc...) as described below. i.e. LS - Locale Specific

Answer (score 5):

You can use `lsCurrencyFormat()` function. First use [`setLocale()`](https://cfdocs.org/setlocale) to set locale information as the one you want (English (UK)) here. Then use [`lsCurrencyFormat()`](https://cfdocs.org/lscurrencyformat).

```
<cfset setLocale('English (UK)')>
<cfset amountInGBP = lsCurrencyFormat(100000, "local")>
<cfoutput>#amountInGBP#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Good @RRK. A few month back I'm also faced the same issue. But I've used replace() to replace a £ instead of $. For example replace(numberFormat('10000','_$,9.99'),'$','£')  Now I can use your setLocal() and iscurrencyFormat(). Thank you RRK.

Comment: See also other [International Functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/international-functions.html).

Comment: There is a recent discussion of a similar issue in Adobe's forums: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10975191#10975191 A reader advised to use: `LSEuroCurrencyFormat`, another one actually recommended `NumberFormat`.